# Swift Combine: prepend() before share() prevents initial sink execution

Tags: ios, swift, macos, combine

I have a setup of publishers similar as in the playground example below.

```
import Combine

let sub1 = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>().prepend("initial 1")//.share()
let sub2 = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>().prepend("initial 2")

Publishers.CombineLatest(sub1, sub2).sink { content1, content2 in
    print("combined received: \(content1) and \(content2)")
}

sub1.sink { content1 in
    print("first received: \(content1)")
}

sub2.sink { content2 in
    print("second received: \(content2)")
}
```

If the `share()` behind the `sub1` is commented out the the following is printed by the console:

```bash
combined received: initial 1 and initial 2
first received: initial 1
second received: initial 2
```

This seems expected. But if the `share()` is present, an unexpected print is produced:

```bash
combined received: initial 1 and initial 2
second received: initial 2
```

In my XCode project I use `prepend()` to trigger an initial execution, but `share()` prevents the initial execution of some of my chains.
Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: "I use prepend() to trigger an initial execution" But that is not how to get an "initial execution" from a Subject. Please show more realistic code.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate please? I am wrapping `NSEvents` and need an initial value for all my publishers. How would I achieve that without `prepend()` ?

Comment: For a subject? With a CurrentValueSubject.

Comment: I have updated my playground to use `CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("initial X")` in line 3 and 4 instead of a `PassthroughSubject` but the code behaves exactly the same. I don't think my way of creating an "initial value" is the issue here.

Comment: That could be and it seems to be the case. But still it's better to be as realistic as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. When you use `share`, you basically change the publisher into reference type semantics. There is just one instance of that `sub1`, and as soon as you subscribe to it with `sink`, it publishes the first element you prepended synchronously (`prepend` is synchronous), and as a result the subscribers you added later *don't* receive the element you prepended.

On the other hand, when you don't use `share`, it's all value semantics. You can think of this as `sink` adds a subscriber to a copy of the publisher, much like how value types are copied. Each of the copies then separately publishes their own "initial 1".

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/share/share()) of `share`, you can see that they worked around this "`share` publishes all the elements synchronously to the first subscriber" problem by adding a delay:

> The following example uses a sequence publisher as a counter to
> publish three random numbers, generated by a `map(_:)` operator. It uses
> a `share()` operator to share the same random number to each of two
> subscribers. This example uses a
> `delay(for:tolerance:scheduler:options:)` operator only to prevent the
> first subscriber from exhausting the sequence publisher immediately;
> an asynchronous publisher wouldn’t need this.

You can do this in your example too:

```
let sub1 = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    .prepend("initial 1")
    .delay(for: 0.1, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .share()
```

And you will see the "first received" line being printed.

Basically, the publisher now `share`s its elements with all its subscribers, if you want an initial element for all the subscribers, you need to figure out *when* exactly does all the subscribers get added (in the above case, after the two `sink`s), and only after that point can you publish the "initial element" (waiting 0.1 seconds is well after that). Otherwise, some subscribers do not receive that element.

Comment: Generally this seems to be the explanation. But, if I add the delay in the playground actually only the `second received: initial 2`  is printed. Any ideas why?
In my code the delay seems to work, but causes other issues.

Comment: @jns_ai_unr You don't seem to have stored the cancellable anywhere? So the subscriptions will get cancelled immediately. Try putting the results of the `sink`s into `let` constants.

Comment: This results in all lines being printed (but in a different order obviously).

Comment: @jns_ai_unr Yeah Another thing you could try in your actual code is to use `.multicast(subject: CurrentValueSubject("")).autoconnect()` instead of `delay`. This is similar to what `share` effectively does, except it uses a `CurrentValueSubject` instead of `PassthroughSubject` so it could store the initial value temporarily I think (I'm not sure if this works in your real code).

Comment: This does work in my code. I found this already based on your initial comment. Thank you!

Comment: One extra note: don't test in a Playground. They don't have a clue!